# PHP language engine

Tags: php, function

I'm writing Content Management software in PHP (which should not be bigger then 3kb when minified), but what engine should I use for languages (english, dutch, german, chinese, etc...)? I was thinking of creating a function called

```
function _(){}
```

that reads strings from a file (a .ini file or similar). But does somebody has an (preferably one with as less code as possible) engine that might be smaller or faster?

I'm not sure if these engines exist already, if not, please say and I will use the _() function.

Comment: o_O You don't minify PHP code!

Comment: Ow yes I will, but I will also include the non minified code in the package

Comment: Agree with Greg. PHP source code is not transferred over the network, so minifying won't help you. If you want a performance boost, you should be using an opcode cache like APC.

Comment: My goal is simply to make the smallest CMS which is still advanced and extensible. Minifying will give a very little performance boost since the hard disc is used less.

Comment: "Minifying will give a very little performance boost since the hard disc is used less." One word: don't.

Comment: "Minifying will give a very little performance boost since the hard disc is used less." No. If you use APC, the opcodes are cached in shared memory, meaning the hard disk is not used at all for script execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `_()` because this is a build-in function for internationalization. You are free to roll your own function (call it `__()`) or use the build-in one which uses the widespread gettext system.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would make my translation function like such (which I believe is very similar to gettext): make it into an sprintf()-like function and translate based on the format string, like so:

```
function __() {
   $a    = func_get_args();
   $a[0] = lookup_translation($a[0]);
   return call_user_func_array("sprintf", $a);
}
```

Now, you can use the function simply like this:

```
echo __("Thanks for logging in, %s!", $username);
```

And in a data file somewhere you have:

```
"Thanks for logging in, %s!"="Merci pour enlogger, %s!" (*)
```

The advantages of this are:

- You don't have to think up identifiers for every single message: `__("login_message", $username)`, `__("logout_message", $username)`, etc...
- You don't immediately have to write a translation for the string, which you would have to if you just used an identifier. You can defer the translation until later, once you're done coding and everything works in English.
- (Similarly) You don't have to translate all strings for all languages at once, but you can do it in chunks

For maximum convenience, I would make the `__` function log untranslated messages somewhere, so you don't have to go hunting for untranslated strings. Let the system tell you what needs to be translated!

(*) Disclaimer: I don't speak French ;)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal, for example, uses function [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6) for this purposes.